# Removing words from start of line to a particular word

Tags: unix

I need a regex to remove the text from the start of line till I encounter the month in this case 'Mar'.
Input string:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 name tara 1461616 Mar  5 18:43 xxx.mapped.v
```

Output string:

```
Mar  5 18:43 xxx.mapped.v
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far, what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do what you want: you can use `cut` do remove obsolete characters, but you can also use the `stat` command for only getting the information you want, as stated in [this URL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803149/how-to-display-modified-time-of-a-file).